# jQuery .removeClass/.toggleClass not working when unchecking a checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have few checkboxes on a page with name and id = selectArticle[]. What I need is that whenever user checks the checkbox, certain elements should get class="required" attached to it and when I uncheck the same box, the class="required" should be deleted.

I have tried .addClass and .removeClass, however whenever i uncheck the checkbox the .remove effect never takes place. However when i Check the checkbox again(in case of .toggleClass), the class toggles perfectly. It seems like it works only on the checkbox 'checked' event and not unchecked.

Through alert, I have checked, both the check/uncheck events are fired perfectly yet the .removeClass/.toggleClass doesnt work at all.

How do I rectify this problem. Please help me out!!!

```
       $("input[name='selectArticle[]']:checkbox").live('change',function(){
          var n = $("input[name='selectArticle[]']:checked").length;
          var id=$(this).val();
          var v = $(this).is(':checked');
          //var vr= $("input[name='selectArticle[]']:unchecked").val();
          //var vr= $(this).val();
          alert(v);
          alert(id);
          //alert("url"+v);
          if($(this).is(':checked'))
          {

            alert('#url'+v);
            $("#title"+id).toggleClass('required');
            $("#id"+id).toggleClass('required');
            $("#url"+id).toggleClass('required url');
            $("#category"+id).toggleClass('required');
            $("#group"+id).toggleClass('required');
          }
          else
          {
            alert("balls"+id);
            ("#title"+id).toggleClass('required');
            $("#id"+id).toggleClass('required');
            $("#url"+id).toggleClass('required url');
            $("#category"+id).toggleClass('required');
            $("#group"+id).toggleClass('required');
          }
         // $("div").text(n + (n <= 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!" + " value :" + v);
    });
```

UPDATE: The answer below

```
    $("input[name='selectArticle[]']:checkbox").live('change',function(){
          var n = $("input[name='selectArticle[]']:checked").length;
          var id=$(this).val();
          var v = $(this).is(':checked');
          //var vr= $("input[name='selectArticle[]']:unchecked").val();
          //var vr= $(this).val();
          alert(v);
          alert(id);
          //alert("url"+v);
          if($(this).is(':checked'))
          {

            alert('#url'+v);
            $("#title"+id).addClass('required');
            $("#id"+id).addClass('required');
            $("#url"+id).addClass('required url');
            $("#category"+id).addClass('required');
            $("#group"+id).addClass('required');
          }

         if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
          {
            alert("balls"+id);
            $("#title"+id).removeClass('required');
            $("#id"+id).removeClass('required');
            $("#url"+id).removeClass('required url');
            $("#category"+id).removeClass('required');
            $("#group"+id).removeClass('required');
          }
         // $("div").text(n + (n <= 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!" + " value :" + v);
    });
```

Comment: yes, they are unique...hence when checked, they fire properly

Comment: There's never any reason (and, frankly, no excuse) to do an `else if` that's just the inverse of the `if` condition. If it's not checked then the `if` condition will fail, so you only need an `else`.

Comment: agreed, and I have an 'else' only currently...but it isnt working :((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As because `toggleClass` is not working try

```
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
    $("#title"+id).removeClass('required');
    ...
}
else
{
    $("#title"+id).addClass('required');
    ...
}
```

Make sure your `var id=$(this).val();` contains something valid because `("#title"+id)`, `$("#id"+id)` and others using same variable.

Comment: `addClass` and `removeClass` insteadof `toggleClass`

Comment: ok, just did that, yet not working..its showing the same behaviour...when checked, it adds the class but when unchecked, it doesnt remove it :((

Comment: I've changed the answer again, please check it again `if checked removeClass` else `addClass`

Comment: i have used a alert(id) and it does show the correct id in both checked/unchecked case

Comment: issue resolved, the problem was in a silly syntax error  ("#title"+id).removeClass('required');
should be  $("#title"+id).removeClass('required');

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the original problem was that you had two IF statements in the UPDATE.  The first one UNCHECKED the box if it was CHECKED but then the second IF statement would re-CHECK the box because it was now UNCHECKED.

If you still have this kind of a set-up then nothing will work properly because you are just flipping the states back and forth.  Make sure you only have an IF-A-THEN-B-ELSE-C and not a IF-A-THEN B followed by a IF-B-THEN-A.

Hope this helps.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Mmm...

```
else if($(this).is(':unchecked'))
```

`:unchecked` is not a valid jQuery selector. Try with just `else` or:

```
if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
```

Comment: done, edited above, still doesnt work. I had tried that earlier

Comment: @SunnyD'Souza Change your `.toggleClass()` in the `if` to `.addClass()`, and in the `else` to `.removeClass()`, and try that.

Comment: ok, just did that, yet not working..its showing the same behaviour...when checked, it adds the class but when unchecked, it doesnt remove it :((